# Integrating across a surface: Multivariable analysis vs Calc 3 parameterization

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In Calculus 3, we compute surface integrals using, most often, a single parametrization.   For instance, over a sphere of radius 1 we could use the simple spherical coordinate transformation that takes a rectangle in $\mathbb R^2, [0,2 \pi]\times [0,\pi] $ to the sphere.

In multivariable analysis, we require that our parametrizations be local diffeomorphisms,  which makes it so that we can't use a single such function but instead need at least 2 overlapping maps with a partition of unity.

My question is:  Why can we get away in Calc 3 calculations without the full local diffeomorphism of our coordinate transformation?  Is it just that we are dealing with "nice" surfaces, "nice" functions,  that the failure point is a simple point,  or some other characteristic that lets us compute these integrals with a single variable transformation instead of multiple overlapping maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calc III we take differentiable maps of the form $\sigma: X=[a,b] \times [c,d] \to S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ in which $\sigma$ is not a bijection only on the boundary. But now look at this,

$$ \int_X \cdot = \int_{X \sqcup \partial X} \cdot  = \int_X  \cdot + \int_{\partial X} \cdot$$

what can you say about $\int_{\partial X} \cdot$ is $\textbf{dim}(X) <2$? It's zero! i.e you can get away with using maps like these to do surface integrals; however, it is a bit inconsistent to use term parametrization in both situations. I used a $\cdot$ above in the integrand because we really don't care about what's inside since we know it'll be a smooth integrable function.